# jQuery File Upload plugin - Empty file upload result

Tags: php, jquery, file, plugins, upload

I've been playing about with [this](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) plugin over the last few days, customising it and setting it up to work exactly as my site requires. I got it all working fine on my localhost server, with no errors/bugs. However, when I try to upload it to my Plesk server, no files are shown onload (even though there are images in  the target folder), and when I try to upload im presented with the " Empty file upload result" error. Oddly.. the file upload seems to work even though its displaying the error, and the relevant images appear in the folder. So it seems to only he having a problem with reading, but not with writing?

I've checked the permissions of the files and thumbnails folder, and set them both to 777, so that cant be the issue.

I really cant see why this is working on my localhost server but not my Plesk server. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: it would help to be able to see your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved this issue. The problem was that my Plesk server was running a very old version of PHP. Updating it to 5.3 seems to have cleared up my issues.